# Connect android phone with PC (Remote administration tool)

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

The task is to connect android phone with a PC and let the PC administrate the phone(for example view screen in live mode), not by usb or wi-fi but over 3G broadband connection.

**I've thought to make things like that:**

1. Open port and send PC the info it needs to connect with phone
2. PC gets the info and connects to phone
3. PC can manage/view/edit files on phone.

But the problem is that i do not know how to do these 3 steps *or* if there is a better solution for that task.

**INFO:**

- Not a single line of code written yet.
- Android phone model not announced(doesn't really matter exactly what model is object but lets take most popular one for example Galaxy S III

//Edit: **Maybe SSH tunneling or something like that ?**